# Python pip install kivy fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, kivy

I want to install [kivy](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html#quickstart)

from command line, I type :

```
pip install cython
pip install pygame
pip install kivy
```

install cython is pass, install pygame is pass, but when I install kivy, got error message:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory

     error: command 'C:\\Users\\Ray\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsof
\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

my environment:
OS:Windows 8.1 64 btis, Python 2.7 32 bits. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you need this: http://glew.sourceforge.net/index.html

Answer (score 0):

a little late for oyu but I ran into the same issue on Windows. The solution might help someone:

I use the following entries in requirements.txt:

```
pygame
kivy.deps.sdl2
kivy.deps.glew
kivy.deps.gstreamer
kivy.deps.angle
kivy==1.10.0
```

I install them like:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```